# Delete from table where two of the three keys in another select

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, delete

I have `tableA` which has 4 columns:

`IDA` (bigint), `IDB` (int), `IDC` (varchar(255)) and `comment` (varchar(255)). The primary key is (`IDA`, `IDB`, `IDC`).

I'm required to delete the records where the count of (`IDA`, `IDB`) is above 1 and the `comment` is "temp". I've come up with the following SQL statement:

`DELETE FROM tableA WHERE IDA, IDB IN 
    (SELECT IDA, IDB FROM tableA  GROUP BY IDA, IDB HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
 AND comment = 'temp'`

But I get the following error: 
"An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','. [...]"

Working on Microsoft SQL Server Enterprise Edition v9.00.3042.00, i.e. SQL Server 2005 Service Pack 2

I'm rather new and appreciate any help/suggestions.

Comment: What should happen if there are 2 rows with same ida+idb but only one of them has comment `'temp'`? Or 6 rows but only one has 'temp'?

Comment: If there are multiple rows with the same `IDA` and `IDB` only the ones with `comment` = "temp" should be deleted.

Comment: It's a bit weird. If there are 2+ rows, all with 'temp', they will all be deleted. If there is only one with 'temp', it will stay.

Comment: If there are 2+ rows for (`IDA`, `IDB`) there will only be a single 'temp' `comment`, defined in the script `INSERT`-ing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is valid SQL but not in SQL-Server. They haven't yet implemented the syntax `(a,b) IN ((1,11), (2,12), ...)` or `(a,b) IN (SELECT expa, expb....)`.

You can work around with either an `EXISTS` subquery:

```
DELETE FROM tableA AS a
WHERE EXISTS
      ( SELECT 1
        FROM tableA AS b
        WHERE b.IDA = a.IDA AND b.IDB = a.IDB 
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
      ) 
  AND a.comment = 'temp' ;
```

or probably more efficiently with a join:

```
DELETE a
FROM tableA AS a
  JOIN
    ( SELECT 
      FROM tableA 
      GROUP BY IDA, IDB
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
   ) AS b
     ON  b.IDA = a.IDA AND b.IDB = a.IDB 
WHERE a.comment = 'temp' ;
```

and even better with a derived table or a cte (no self-join):

```
WITH dups AS
  ( SELECT comment, 
           cnt = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY IDA, IDB)
     FROM tableA 
  ) 
DELETE 
FROM dups
WHERE comment = 'temp' 
  AND cnt > 1 ;
```

Comment: I'm using the solution with the derived table. thank you very much for your guidance!